# Want to add checkboxes to dynamically created li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code. This adds li dynamically to the  with id "list". How can I add to every li a checkbox?

```js
  $("#add").on("click", function(e){
    $("#list").append("<li>" + $("#prenume").val() + " " + $("#nume").val() + "</li>");
    return false;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
      Prenume
      <input type="text" id="prenume"></input>
      Nume
      <input type="text" id="nume"></input>
</form>

<button id="add">Add</button>

<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: put a checkbox inside of it in the html markup?

Comment: Have you tried actually just adding the checkbox when you append the `li`?

Comment: I tried but when I hit the add button it adds one. Then when I want to make another li it adds another checkbox to the first li created than it adds one to the second one and so one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you append the li in your JavaScript, add an input element with the type checkbox.

```js
$("#add").on("click", function(e){
    $("#list").append("<li><input type='checkbox'>" + $("#prenume").val() + " " + $("#nume").val() + "</li>");
    return false;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
      Prenume
      <input type="text" id="prenume"></input>
      Nume
      <input type="text" id="nume"></input>
</form>

<button id="add">Add</button>

<ul id="list">
</ul>
```